# How to pass data to a View in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to pass data to `SingleTodo` view in Backbone.js. But, it is not passing properly.
For more clarity, please see the code and outputs given below.

**Code:**
**temp.html**

```html
<h1>This is Temp</h1>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="app-template">
  Title: <%= title %><br/>
  isCompleted: <%= isCompleted %>
</script>
```

**temp.js**

```js
const SingleTodo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    title: "",
    isCompleted: false
  }
});

const TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#app",
  template: _.template($("#app-template").html()),

  initialize: function () {
    this.model = new SingleTodo();
    this.render();
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  const todoView = new TodoView();

  todoView.model.set({
    title: "A simple to-do",
    isCompleted: true
  });
});
```

**Output:**
**Expected**
[image: Expected]

**Getting**
[image: Getting]

What is wrong in my code because of which I am not getting expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the following line in the `initialize` method of `TodoView`:

```js
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

Aside: instead of setting `this.model` inside the view's `initialize` method, I recommend passing it from the outside. In your example, change the first line of the `$(document).ready` handler:

```js
const todoView = new TodoView({model: new SingleTodo()});
```